# Store more apps on iPhone 5c 16gb

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, icloud

So I recently moved from an Android phone to an iPhone 5c. One of my favorite features of Android was the ability to store apps on the SD card. It's apparent that there's no solution like this for an iPhone, as iPhones don't have an SD card slot. My question, however, is what alternatives may exist to storing extra apps on my 5c. I've come to find out that apps alone are filling my device. Using iCloud, I can sync just about everything else wirelessly, but regardless, I still could use some more breathing room just for my apps. Is there any sort of cloud based solution for this, or anything else for that matter? I've hunted around but can't seem to find any definitive answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't anything that I'm aware of (aside from @ArchonOSX's answer). My understanding is that the higher capacity models of it's iOS lineup are an integral part of it's profits. Also, because of the sandboxing that happens (which helps make iOS very secure), options become mainly limited to web-apps - which are in some cases plentiful - for storing the bulk of the app elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the only option is to have all the apps you want on iTunes and load them onto your iPhone as desired. Of course you can't have them all at the same time because of your memory limitations but you could change sets for vacation or work for instance.

Or you can buy an iPhone with more memory.

Those are the only options Apple leaves you.

Happy Day!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking something like this might have to be the solution. It might not be super elegant but at least it's a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not have the concept of a file system for users to access in the first place. Even if you use a dock to USB / camera card adapter, the OS will read files from th storage and ingest them into the photo app.

Short of a jailbreak, you will not be able to extend the storage in an analogous manner to Android, OS X, Windows of other computer-like OS.

Comment: This is a bit unrelated. Perhaps I was unclear. I'm mainly looking for a way to run apps from the cloud.

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns  Perhaps I should have finished the thought. Not only can you not run apps on local storage, you cannot run them on network attached storage. With iTunes radio, we have the beginnings of a streaming service, but apps seem quite a long while till they would be cloud sourced.